# Use of the Gtk.GLArea in Pygobject GTK3

Tags: opengl, gtk, pygobject

The documentation for use of the python wrappers for Gtk3 are somewhat limited. I have found several of the common widget examples. I am trying to use the Gtk.GLArea widget. The API documentation is for C and I have not had much luck guessing the equivalent python calls to use this widget. In the example the widget is created using the following C code:

```
 // create a GtkGLArea instance
GtkWidget *gl_area = gtk_gl_area_new ();
g_signal_connect (gl_area, "render", G_CALLBACK (render), NULL);
```

Then the render function has OpenGL commands in it:

```
static gboolean
render (GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context)
{
  // inside this function it's safe to use GL; the given
  // #GdkGLContext has been made current to the drawable
  // surface used by the #GtkGLArea and the viewport has
  // already been set to be the size of the allocation

  // we can start by clearing the buffer
  glClearColor (0, 0, 0, 0);
  glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // draw your object
  draw_an_object ();

  // we completed our drawing; the draw commands will be
  // flushed at the end of the signal emission chain, and
  // the buffers will be drawn on the window
  return TRUE;
}
```

My question is how do you do the equivalent in python?

This is my attempt:

```
class RootWidget(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='GL Example')
        self.set_default_size(800,500)
        gl = Gtk.GLArea()
        gl.connect("render", self.gl_render)
        self.add(gl)


    def gl_render(self, gl):
        print(gl)
        Gtk.glClearColor(0,0,0,1)
        Gtk.glClear(Gtk.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        return True
```

You'll notice I added "Gtk." to the gl commands. Not sure if this is correct but python has no idea what a glClearColor is in the function. I'm not super familiar with C namespaces but I can't figure out how the C function would understand what the gl commands are, either. The program does run and I receive the following errors in the console:

> fb setup not supported
>
> (python.exe:120048): Gdk-WARNING **: Compile failure in fragment
> shader:
>
> ERROR: 0:5: 'gl_FragColor' : undeclared identifier
>
> ERROR: 0:5: 'texture2D' : no matching overloaded function found (using
> implicit conversion)

Any input on this would be useful. My hope is to be able to use opengl commands to draw in a fixed widget area.

edit:
This is my latest attempt. In the `on_render()` function I print the context and I do see the context property is set to a `<gtk.gdk.Win32GLContext object at 0x3f133f0>` and debugging does show that that is the current context. Problem is I still get the same shader, Frag_Color, and texture errors and I'm not even calling any gl commands.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *


class MyGLArea(Gtk.GLArea):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.GLArea.__init__(self)
        self.connect("realize", self.on_realize)


    def on_realize(self, area):
        ctx = self.get_context()
        ctx.make_current()
        print("The context is {}".format(self.get_property("context")))
        err = self.get_error()
        if err:
            print(err)
        return



class RootWidget(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='GL Example')
        self.set_default_size(800,500)
        gl_area = MyGLArea()
        self.add(gl_area)


win = RootWidget()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

edit 2:
Seems as if I am just having a installation issue with the GLArea widget. Seems odd since I'm using over 30 different Gtk widgets without issue. I have errors just adding the widget and not even sending commands. I ran code in Ubuntu python interpreter and it doesn't have any error creating the widget. I am having some issues with certain GL commands but may be from the python wrapper I installed. I'm still looking for the widget equivalent to pygame's or glut's init and set projection functions to setup the viewport. If anyone got ideas I'd love to hear them. The following code does run without errors:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *


class MyGLArea(Gtk.GLArea):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.GLArea.__init__(self)
        self.connect("realize", self.on_realize)
        self.connect("render", self.render)


    def on_realize(self, area):
        ctx = self.get_context()
        ctx.make_current()
        err = self.get_error()
        if err:
            print("The error is {}".format(err))

    def render(self, area, ctx):
        glClearColor(1,0,0,1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        return True

class RootWidget(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='GL Example')
        self.set_default_size(800,500)
        gl_area = MyGLArea()
        self.add(gl_area)

win = RootWidget()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: The python doc: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/GLArea.html . But I agree that examples are in C, and that's a problem.

Comment: glClearColor is not inside GTK, it's in the opengl library: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearColor.xhtml . There must be some python wrapper for that library, which seems to be named PyOpenGL: http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Here's a PyOpenGL tutorial which should get you started: https://pythonprogramming.net/opengl-rotating-cube-example-pyopengl-tutorial/

Comment: @liberforce Thanks. That clears up where the gl commands come from. I did run the pygame tutorial and it works exactly the way I want to use it in gtk except instead of a separate window it would be a widget. Reading the API docs for a  Gdk.GLContext, once the context is made "current" it will accept gl commands. I am getting gl error before I even send any.

Answer (score 3):

Using the All-In-One installer for windows I noticed there is an option for OpenGL Extentions to GTK+. Now it works as expected.
Here's some working code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL import shaders
import numpy as np

FRAGMENT_SOURCE ='''
#version 330
in vec4 inputColor;
out vec4 outputColor;
void main(){
outputColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);//constant red. I know it's a poor shader
};'''

VERTEX_SOURCE = '''
#version 330
in vec4 position;
void main(){
gl_Position =  position;
}'''

class MyGLArea(Gtk.GLArea):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.GLArea.__init__(self)
        self.connect("realize", self.on_realize)
        self.connect("render", self.on_render)

    def on_realize(self, area):
        ctx = self.get_context()
        print("realized", ctx)

    def on_render(self, area, ctx):
        ctx.make_current()
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        VERTEX_SHADER_PROG = shaders.compileShader(VERTEX_SOURCE, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        FRAGMENT_SHADER_PROG = shaders.compileShader(FRAGMENT_SOURCE, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        self.shader_prog = shaders.compileProgram(VERTEX_SHADER_PROG, FRAGMENT_SHADER_PROG)
        self.create_object()

    def create_object(self):
        # Create a new VAO (Vertex Array Object) and bind it
        vertex_array_object = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object)
        # Generate buffers to hold our vertices
        vertex_buffer = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer)
        # Get the position of the 'position' in parameter of our shader and bind it.
        position = glGetAttribLocation(self.shader_prog, 'position')
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(position)
        # Describe the position data layout in the buffer
        glVertexAttribPointer(position, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
        # Send the data over to the buffer
        vertices = np.array([-0.6, -0.6, 0.0,
                             0.0, 0.6, 0.0,
                             0.6, -0.6, 0.0,
                             0.7, -0.1, 0.0,
                             0.8, 0.1, 0.0,
                             0.9, -0.1, 0.0
                             ], dtype=np.float32)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 96, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        # Unbind the VAO first (Important)
        glBindVertexArray(0)
        # Unbind other stuff
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(position)




        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        self.display(vertex_array_object)

    def display(self, vert):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glUseProgram(self.shader_prog)
        glBindVertexArray(vert)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 4, 3)
        glBindVertexArray(0)
        glUseProgram(0)

class RootWidget(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='GL Example')
        self.set_default_size(800, 500)
        gl_area = MyGLArea()
        gl_area.set_has_depth_buffer(False)
        gl_area.set_has_stencil_buffer(False)
        self.add(gl_area)

win = RootWidget()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

[image: Triangle]
[image: Install Options]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this works for you, but it did work for me.

The Python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf, Gdk
from OpenGL.GL import glClearColor, glClear, glFlush, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT
import os, sys

UI_FILE = "pygtk_gtkglarea.ui"

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):

        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(UI_FILE)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        gl_area = Gtk.GLArea()
        gl_area.connect('render', self.area_render)
        gl_area.connect('realize', self.area_realize)
        #gl_area.connect('create-context', self.area_context)
        box = self.builder.get_object('box1')
        box.pack_end(gl_area, True, True, 0)

        window = self.builder.get_object('window')
        window.show_all()

    def area_realize (self, gl_area):       
        error = gl_area.get_error()
        if error != None:
            print("your graphics card is probably too old : ", error)
        else:
            print(gl_area, "realize... fine so far")

    def area_context(self, gl_area):
        # not needed except for special instances, read the docs
        c = gl_area.get_context()
        print(c , "context")
        return c

    def area_render(self, area, context):
        #print gl_area
        #print gl_context
        glClearColor (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glFlush()
        print("rendering... done")
        return True

    def on_window_destroy(self, window):
        Gtk.main_quit()

def main():
    app = GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

And the pygtk_gtkglarea.ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.0"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">window</property>
    <property name="default_width">500</property>
    <property name="default_height">400</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: @ theGtknerd Your code does work for me (although i had to add glFlush to the import). As soon as I add a drawing command to it is the problem. I add glColor3f(1.0,0.0,1.0) after glClear() and it crashes. Same with any glBegin(GL_LINES) or similar.Again, this could be a problem with my gl library. I assume the gl_FragColor error I get is due to what ever fragment shader code it is trying to run. I have also tried compiling and using shaders without luck.

Comment: @AdamSolchenberger Let me try your additions tomorrow and I will update. Sorry about that import.

Comment: @AdamSolchenberger I have the same problem with glColor3f. Sadly, I am not good with OpenGL. I had the code snippet I posted from helping with another project.