# Gtk GLArea Widget in C not displaying gl commands

Tags: c, opengl, gtk, gobject, gdk

I have asked a question earlier ([Use of the Gtk.GLArea in Pygobject GTK3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565884/use-of-the-gtk-glarea-in-pygobject-gtk3)) about trying to use the GLArea widget in PyGObject. I never did get the python version to draw commands so I thought I'd give the c version a try to understand it better. Using Ubuntu 16 since Gtk3 is all included, I gave it a shot. The following code compiles and runs without errors or warning but does not draw the included GL_LINES instructions. The really odd thing is changing the glClearColor does change the background and the GL_LINES are in the same function. As you can see I'm using the Ubuntu included epoxy/gl library, which I believe would be equivalent to GL/gl. Any ideas?

```
/*to compile -> 
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o gl_area gl_area.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 epoxy`*/
#include <math.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <epoxy/gl.h>
#include <stdio.h>


gint init(GtkWidget *widget)
{
  /* Setup the viewport*/
      glViewport(0, 0,  gtk_widget_get_allocated_width (widget),
                        gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(widget));
      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
      glLoadIdentity();
      glOrtho(0,100, 100,0, -1,1);
      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
      glLoadIdentity();

      printf("ran init method\n");
      return TRUE;
}



/* When widget is exposed it's contents are redrawn. */
static gboolean
render (GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context)
{
  /* OpenGL functions can be called only if make_current returns true */

      /* Draw simple triangle */
      glClearColor(.3,.3,.3,1);
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      glColor4f(1,1,1,1);
      glBegin(GL_LINES);
{
      glVertex2f(0,0);
      glVertex2f(10000,10000);
      glVertex2f(0,0);
      glVertex2f(-10000,-10000);
      glVertex2f(0,0);
      glVertex2f(10000,-10000);
      glVertex2f(0,0);
      glVertex2f(-10000,10000);
}
      glEnd();
      printf("ran render method\n");
  return TRUE;
}

/* When glarea widget size changes, viewport size is set to match the new size */
gint reshape(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventConfigure *event)
{
  /* OpenGL functions can be called if context is current */
      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
      glLoadIdentity();
      printf("ran rehsape method\n");
    glViewport(0, 0, gtk_widget_get_allocated_width (widget),
                        gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(widget));
  return TRUE;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
/* initialize gtk */
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

/* Create new top level window. */
GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GL Area Test");
gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW(window),
                             640,
                            480);
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);

  /* Quit main if got delete event */
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window),
                    "delete-event",
                    G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), 
                    NULL);

  /* Create new OpenGL widget. */
GtkWidget *glarea = gtk_gl_area_new ();

  /* Do initialization when widget has been realized. */
 g_signal_connect(glarea, "realize",  G_CALLBACK(init), NULL);
  /* When window is resized viewport needs to be resized also. */
 g_signal_connect(glarea, "configure-event",  G_CALLBACK(reshape), NULL);

  /* Render signal should be sent once the context is set to current. */
g_signal_connect (glarea, "render", G_CALLBACK (render), NULL);


  /* set minimum size */
 gtk_widget_set_size_request(glarea, 100,100);

  /* put glarea into window and show it all */
 gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), glarea);
 gtk_widget_show_all (window);
 gtk_main();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, probably not the error but: after `glOrtho(0,100, 100,0, -1,1);` you call `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);` again and `glLoadIdentity();`. This overrides the previous call of `glOrtho()`. (If I remember right this is like `glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);`.) However, I assume you intended to write `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);` (for the second call of `glMatrixMode()`) instead.

Comment: Completeley unrelated but you're supposed to connect to `destroy`, not `delete-event` to call `gtk_main_quit`.

Comment: Please run `gtk-demo`, give a look to the gl example there, maybe you'll see what you're doing wrong? The example is here too: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/demos/gtk-demo/glarea.c

Answer (score 1):

[image]Ok, I understand a lot more about openGL and the use of shaders. Basically, the problem the GLArea was having was the commands were not in an array that was "bound" to the current context's active buffer. This tut helped a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_kFcRlLTk0 I hacked up the demo code to simplify it and brought the shader source code into the c code as strings. As it was, it would open from the demo app and had sliders to rotate the triangle by a matrix. I tried to distill it down to the most basic window. This does compile and run without error. Now I will try it in PyGObject.

```
/* OpenGL Area
 *
 * GtkGLArea is a widget that allows custom drawing using OpenGL calls.
 */
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <epoxy/gl.h>

const GLchar *FRAGMENT_SOURCE =
"#version 330\n"
"in vec4 inputColor;\n"
"out vec4 outputColor;\n"
"void main() {\n"
"outputColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);\n" //constant red. I know it's a poor shader
"}";
const GLchar  *VERTEX_SOURCE =
"#version 330\n"
"in vec4 position;\n"
"void main()\n{gl_Position =  position;\n"
"}";


/* the GtkGLArea widget */
static GtkWidget *gl_area = NULL;

/* The object we are drawing */
static const GLfloat vertex_data[] = {
  0.f,   0.5f,   0.f, 1.f,
  0.5f, -0.366f, 0.f, 1.f,
 -0.5f, -0.366f, 0.f, 1.f,
};

/* Initialize the GL buffers */
static void
init_buffers (GLuint *vao_out,
              GLuint *buffer_out)
{
  GLuint vao, buffer;

  /* We only use one VAO, so we always keep it bound */
  glGenVertexArrays (1, &vao);
  glBindVertexArray (vao);

  /* This is the buffer that holds the vertices */
  glGenBuffers (1, &buffer);
  glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof (vertex_data), vertex_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

  if (vao_out != NULL)
    *vao_out = vao;

  if (buffer_out != NULL)
    *buffer_out = buffer;
}

/* Create and compile a shader */
static GLuint
create_shader (int  type)
{
  GLuint shader;
  int status;
  shader = glCreateShader (type);
if (type== GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER){
  glShaderSource (shader, 1, &FRAGMENT_SOURCE, NULL);}
if (type== GL_VERTEX_SHADER){
  glShaderSource (shader, 1, &VERTEX_SOURCE, NULL);}
  glCompileShader (shader);

  glGetShaderiv (shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
  if (status == GL_FALSE)
    {
      int log_len;
      char *buffer;
      glGetShaderiv (shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_len);
      buffer = g_malloc (log_len + 1);
      glGetShaderInfoLog (shader, log_len, NULL, buffer);
      g_warning ("Compile failure in %s shader:\n%s",
                 type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment",
                 buffer);
      g_free (buffer);
      glDeleteShader (shader);
      return 0;
    }

  return shader;
}

/* Initialize the shaders and link them into a program */
static void
init_shaders (GLuint *program_out)
{
  GLuint vertex, fragment;
  GLuint program = 0;
  int status;
  vertex = create_shader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

  if (vertex == 0)
    {
      *program_out = 0;
      return;
    }

  fragment = create_shader (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

  if (fragment == 0)
    {
      glDeleteShader (vertex);
      *program_out = 0;
      return;
    }

  program = glCreateProgram ();
  glAttachShader (program, vertex);
  glAttachShader (program, fragment);

  glLinkProgram (program);

  glGetProgramiv (program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
  if (status == GL_FALSE)
    {
      int log_len;
      char *buffer;

      glGetProgramiv (program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_len);

      buffer = g_malloc (log_len + 1);
      glGetProgramInfoLog (program, log_len, NULL, buffer);

      g_warning ("Linking failure:\n%s", buffer);

      g_free (buffer);

      glDeleteProgram (program);
      program = 0;

      goto out;
    }


  glDetachShader (program, vertex);
  glDetachShader (program, fragment);

out:
  glDeleteShader (vertex);
  glDeleteShader (fragment);

  if (program_out != NULL)
    *program_out = program;

}


static GLuint position_buffer;
static GLuint program;

/* We need to set up our state when we realize the GtkGLArea widget */
static void
realize (GtkWidget *widget)
{
  GdkGLContext *context;
  gtk_gl_area_make_current (GTK_GL_AREA (widget));
  if (gtk_gl_area_get_error (GTK_GL_AREA (widget)) != NULL)
    return;
  context = gtk_gl_area_get_context (GTK_GL_AREA (widget));
  init_buffers (&position_buffer, NULL);
  init_shaders (&program);
}

/* We should tear down the state when unrealizing */
static void
unrealize (GtkWidget *widget)
{
  gtk_gl_area_make_current (GTK_GL_AREA (widget));

  if (gtk_gl_area_get_error (GTK_GL_AREA (widget)) != NULL)
    return;

  glDeleteBuffers (1, &position_buffer);
  glDeleteProgram (program);
}

static void
draw_triangle (void)
{

  /* Use our shaders */
  glUseProgram (program);


  /* Use the vertices in our buffer */
  glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, position_buffer);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);
  glVertexAttribPointer (0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
  /* Draw the three vertices as a triangle */
  glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

  /* We finished using the buffers and program */
  glDisableVertexAttribArray (0);
  glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  glUseProgram (0);
}

static gboolean
render (GtkGLArea    *area,
        GdkGLContext *context)
{
  if (gtk_gl_area_get_error (area) != NULL)
    return FALSE;

  /* Clear the viewport */
  glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  /* Draw our object */
  draw_triangle ();

  /* Flush the contents of the pipeline */
  glFlush ();

  return TRUE;
}

static void
on_axis_value_change (void)
{
  gtk_widget_queue_draw (gl_area);
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
GtkWidget *window, *box;
/* initialize gtk */
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
/* Create new top level window. */
window = gtk_window_new( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW(window),1000,1000);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GL Area");
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, FALSE);
    g_object_set (box, "margin", 12, NULL);
    gtk_box_set_spacing (GTK_BOX (box), 6);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box);
gl_area = gtk_gl_area_new ();
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(box), gl_area,1,1, 0);
    /* We need to initialize and free GL resources, so we use
    * the realize and unrealize signals on the widget
    */
    g_signal_connect (gl_area, "realize", G_CALLBACK (realize), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (gl_area, "unrealize", G_CALLBACK (unrealize), NULL);

    /* The main "draw" call for GtkGLArea */
    g_signal_connect (gl_area, "render", G_CALLBACK (render), NULL);
    /* Quit form main if got delete event */
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "delete-event",
                   G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window));
gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```